# Copy a database file from one directory to another With in a project

Tags: android, sqlite, file-io, fileutils

I am working on an android application where i have to copy a database file I have tried with Files.Copy() method but my project API is higher than copy() method. So I started to use FileUtils.CopyFile() method please check the code below.

I am getting the logs and no error messages or logs but the file is not getting copied. Any help is welcome Thanks in advance.

````
        //String backupDbValue = QolsysSettingsAPI.getValue(SettingKeyConstants.BACK_UP);
        Qlog.d(TAG, "backUpProtocol() method called");
        File myObj = new File("/data/data/com.qolsys.qolsysprovider/databases/student.db");
        File copyObj = new File("/system/etc");
        FileUtils.copyFile(myObj, copyObj);
        Qlog.d(TAG, " myobj " + myObj.getAbsolutePath() + " copyobj " + copyObj.getAbsolutePath());
    }```
````

Comment: You have a rooted phone?

Comment: No, can you explain what can i do with rooted device

Comment: `File copyObj = new File("/system/etc");` If your device is not rooted then explain what you want to do in /system/etc ? Creating a file in that directory? WIll not go as it is read only.

Comment: Does not copyFile() return a boolean?

Comment: Oh thanks a lot actually i don't know all this stuff. So, can you suggest me a better way to do the task without rooted phone.

Comment: I do not know which task you have to accomplish as you did not say such.

Comment: I just have to copy a db file to system/etc is it possible or not. Else tell me that can i copy that db file in any other directory with above logic code. Thanks In Advance.

Comment: I cannot check the code as i have no qt but it looks ok. So just choose a path that is writable.